# Java : Android ; 'The literal 08 of type int is out of range'

Tags: java, android

```
db.adddebugger(04, "millioffsetseccount(long) : long");
db.adddebugger(05, "millitotaloffset(tinst) : long");
db.adddebugger(06, "grenumberofdaysinyear(long) : long");
db.adddebugger(07, "initialize(tinst) : tinst");
db.adddebugger(08, "hbcopy(tinst,tinst : void");
db.adddebugger(09, "randInt(int,int)");
db.adddebugger(10, "hebWDHHtoHalakim(int,int,int,int):long");
```

08, and 09 throw an X and will not allow it to compile, yet 10 will.

18 also works (seeing if it is filtering for octal)

any idea why only 08, and 09 would throw an error?

Answer (score 8):

`0n` is parsed as a number in ocal base.

`08` and `09` do not exist in octal base, since the only valid digits in that base are 0 to 7.

`18` works, since without the leading 0, the number is parsed as a decimal number.